# Raw SQL to Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Could you help me convert this SQL query to Eloquent:

```
SELECT *
FROM rooms r
WHERE r.id NOT IN (
    SELECT b.room_id FROM bookings b
    WHERE NOT (b.time_to   <= '2019-11-18'
               OR
               b.time_from >= '2019-11-22'))
ORDER BY r.id;
```

In Laravel I have two models, **Room** and **Booking**. How create in eloquent **WHERE NOT** ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have a problem with middle select, I don't know how to do **WHERE NOT**

Comment: What does that mean? Where's the code showing your "problem"? Please provide your attempts and some sample input and output data such that others can reproduce your problem

Comment: Don't down vote  him guys. He is new here. we should try to understand. please remove your down vote.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that your models are in app\Models Folder.

```
$date1 = "2019-11-18";
$date2 = "2019-11-22";
$rooms = Room::whereDoesntHave("bookings", function($query) use ($date1, $date2){
    return $query->where(function($where_query)  use ($date1, $date2){
        return $where_query->whereDate("time_to", "<=", $date2)
        ->orWhereDate("time_from", ">=", $date1 );
    });
})->orderBy("id", "ASC");
```

**Your Room model must have a relation with bookings**

```
public function bookings(){
    return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Booking", "room_id", "id");
}
```

If explanation needed please ask.

Comment: it gave me bad results, in my query are 2x NOT

Comment: @Damian checkout new Edit.

Comment: @Damian because some one down vote you. Click the tick mark of correct answer right below of Up Vote and down vote.

Answer (score 0):

you need to opposite the condition.
instead of :

```
WHERE NOT (b.time_to   <= '2019-11-18'
           OR
           b.time_from >= '2019-11-22')
```

do:

```
WHERE (b.time_to   > '2019-11-18'
        AND 
       b.time_from < '2019-11-22')
```

using laravel eloquent:

```
Model::where('column','>','2019-11-18')
->where('column','<','2019-11-22')->orderBy('id','ASC')->get()
```

Comment: I think you should replace OR -> AND, then it will work